# Extract the year from the given date?

Tags: mysql

I have a date field create_at in Y-m-d format in my table. I want to extract only the year from that field.

I tried YEAR(create_at) which gives result in comma separated value.

Eg.

```
2017-5-12 outputs 2,017. I need without the comma.
```

Comment: [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) just returns an integer (between 1000 and 9999). It is formatting in your application that is putting the `,` in the value.

Comment: @Nick so what should i do to fix this

Comment: Without seeing your application code that's impossible to answer...

Answer (score 0):

The YEAR() will provide you integer output only.

```
SELECT YEAR("2017-06-15");
2017
```

Ref https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_year